# Firebase Cloud Messaging - PHP Rest API not working for iOS

Tags: php, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the PHP code given below to send notification with custom payload through Firebase Cloud Messaging. It is working for Android but not for the iOS.

However, I am able to receive notification sent from firebase cloud messaging console. Kindly advise.

```
public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message, $title, $sound, 
$purpose) 
{

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => array(
                        "for" => $purpose,
                        "id" => strtotime("now"),
                        "message" => $message,
                        "title" => $title,
                        "sound" => $sound,
                         "vibrate" => 1,
                        "date" => date("D d, M Y h:i A"),
                        "priority"=>'high',
                        "content_available"=>false
                        ),
        'time_to_live' => 600,
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . FCM_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: When you say " It is working for Android but not for the iOS."  are you referring to waking the app from background?

Comment: If you have already tried sending iOS devices messages with the `notification` tag then your issue might be how you are handling the messages in the `AppDelegate` file.  Edit your question and add the message structure you have tried for iOS and also add the code you use in you `AppDelegate` to handle the messages in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android and iOS handle Push Notifications differently. While Android will only wake from background when only the `data` tag is provided, iOS devices require the `notification` tag to deal with notifications received while the app is in the background.

Comment: I have also tried with the notification tag, with title and message keys but still not able to receive notification.

Comment: @MudassirShah :: Edit your question and add the message structure you have tried for iOS and also add the code you use in you `AppDelegate` to handle the messages in iOS.